# How can I make my console print the values as opposed to showing undefined

Tags: javascript

```
const howLong = 5
```

```
let special = [
    "!",
    "@",
    "#",
    "$",
    "%",
    "+",
    "&",];

let finalPassword = []

for (let i = 0; i < howLong; i++) { 
    finalPassword += special[Math.floor(Math.random() * howLong)].push
    
}
```

console prints undefined 5x, my goal is to make it copy 5 random characters from the "special" array into a new var "finalPassword"

Comment: To begin with, `let finalPassword = "";`.

Comment: `.push` is wrong. And `+=` is wrong. It should be `finalPassword.push(special[Math.floor(Math.random() * howLong)])` or instead make `finalPassword` a string and use `+=` but remove `.push`.

Comment: You don't show anywhere that you are printing to the console.

Comment: I was unable to post it because there was too much text.

Comment: What's your expected output? A string? An array?

Answer (score 0):

you should remove the .push call

```
const howLong = 5;    
let special = [
        "!",
        "@",
        "#",
        "$",
        "%",
        "+",
        "&",];
    
    let finalPassword = "";    
    for (let i = 0; i < howLong; i++) { 
        finalPassword += special[Math.floor(Math.random() * howLong)]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your expected output requirements are you can either concatenate "special" characters on to a string:

```js
const howLong = 5;

let special=["!","@","#","$","%","+","&"];

let finalPassword = '';

for (let i = 0; i < howLong; i++) { 
  const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * howLong);
  finalPassword += special[rnd];
}

console.log(finalPassword);
```

...or you can push those "special" characters into an array (and then maybe `join` up that array of elements into a string).

```js
const howLong = 5;

let special=["!","@","#","$","%","+","&"];

let finalPassword = [];

for (let i = 0; i < howLong; i++) { 
  const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * howLong);
  finalPassword.push(special[rnd]);
}

console.log(finalPassword);
console.log(finalPassword.join(''));
```

But you can't do both operations at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop iteration, generate a random index and then access the special array in that index to fetch the special character.

```js
const howLong = 5;

let special = [
    "!",
    "@",
    "#",
    "$",
    "%",
    "+",
    "&",];

let finalPassword = []

for (let i = 0; i < howLong; i++) { 
    const currentRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * howLong);
    finalPassword.push(special[currentRandom]);
}

console.log(finalPassword);
```

Answer (score -1):

In your example you simply have to remove `.push` it seems.

```js
let special = ["!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "+", "&"];

let finalPassword = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  finalPassword += special[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];
}

console.log({ finalPassword });
```

Comment: If `finalPassword` is an array why are you trying to use `+=` with it?

Comment: The question was to log a value instead of undefined, I’m not loosing time on technicalities, it’s pretty obvious you should not do that.

Comment: Repeating the same problems from the question in your answer doesn't make it a good answer. The code _is_ the technicalities.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me a valuable lesson :+1